# norm for all columns in a pandas datafrme

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

With a dataframe like this:

```
index  col_1   col_2   ...   col_n
0      0.2     0.1           0.3
1      0.2     0.1           0.3
2      0.2     0.1           0.3
...
n      0.4     0.7           0.1
```

How can one get the norm for each column ?
Where the norm is the sqrt of the sum of the squares.

I am able to do this for each column sequentially, but am unsure how to vectorize (avoiding a for loop) the same to an answer:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


norm_col_1 = np.linalg.norm(df[col_1])
norm_col_2 = np.linalg.norm(df[col_2])

norm_col_n = np.linalg.norm(df[col_n])
```

the answer would be a new dataframe series like this:

```
        norms
col_1   0.111
col_2   0.202
col_3   0.55
...
con_n   0.100
```

Comment: `df.apply(np.linalg.norm)`

Comment: @BeRT2me,  thanks, but i tried that and it produces one value whereas a series is required.   The answer posted is closer `np.linalg.norm(df, axis=0)`...

Comment: That produces a Series with column headers as the index... the only way it could be 'producing one value' is if your DataFrame looks different from what you've posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the entire DataFrame to [`np.linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), along with an `axis` argument of 0 to tell it to apply it column-wise:

```
np.linalg.norm(df, axis=0)
```

To create a series with appropriate column names, try:

```
results = pd.Series(data=np.linalg.norm(df, axis=0), index=df.columns)
```